# pythonw.exe completely dysfunctional on windows

Tags: python-3.2

Whenever I try to use the python interpreter on windows,

```
C:\path>pythonw.exe cubes.py
<blank line>
C:\path>
```

happens.

using `python.exe` instead works, but every tutorial tells me to use pythonw.exe.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t752828-pythonw-exe.html, which I quickly verified myself:

> pythonw.exe is the same as python.exe but it doesn't open a console
>   window, and launches python in the background. This allows you to
>   easily run background programs or GUI programs in a nicer way (without
>   a dummy console window popping up).

This is precisely what you see. Don't use pythonw.exe if you want an interactive interpreter.

Comment: Not exactly the same, even for GUI apps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114018/python-script-works-with-py-extension-but-not-with-pyw-extension/10114171#10114171

Comment: Wow... what can I say.. nothing is as simple as it seems. Again, I'd encourage you to put your comments into answers :)

Comment: Your answer is perfectly adequate to answer his question. I'd vote it up but I'm afraid I'd hit the serial upvoter limit since I looked through a bunch of your old posts in the last few days.